# Whether the proof created by prover can be tampered in ZoKrates?

Tags: zksnark, zokrates, proof

I am studying zokrates recently. I know that the prover will finally generate a proof, and then the verifier can use this proof and public input as input to verify whether the prover has certain knowledge. I want to know if it is possible for the prover to tamper with the proof, and then the tampered proof can also pass the verification of the verifier. I guess it should not work in theory, but I want to know why.

Hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: This question might be better fitted to https://ethresear.ch/ or https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I don't know if you are familiar with zokrates. I want to implement transactions on Ethereum based on zokrates, but I can't seem to find any examples to refer to. Most of the examples of zokrates are not able to implement transactions on Ethereum. I don't know if you have any experience in this area. thank!